# C# winform cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'

Tags: c#, winforms

In the program, I want to add button column inside the DatagridView. However, I get the error which is **cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'**. I plan to put the button column code at this class because when I click the refresh button, it would not duplicate the data in dataGridView. Any suggestion to solve this problem?

```
public DataTable StudentData()
{
    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    data.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
    data.Columns.Add("No.", typeof(string));

    //....
    DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbutton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn { Text = "Click", UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true };                     
    data.Columns.Add(dgvbutton);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: a `DataGridView` is not the same as a `DataTable`.  A `DataGridView*Column` is added to a `DataGridView` not a `DataTable`.  That should be eminently clear from the error text

Comment: Move the button part from this method to not confuse yourself. It is in the wrong place. Use the function to create and return the `DataTable`, and after you bind it to the grid (YourDataGridView.DataSource = StudentData();`), add the button part, create and add it to the `YourDataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvbutton);` collection.

Comment: If you have to reset the `.DataSource` again, then you need also to clear the column collection (`dgv.Columns.Clear();`).

Comment: @dr.null Thanks for the advise. Problem solved.